# Cordova VS Phonegap plugins

Tags: android, ios, cordova

Sorry if it's a stupid question but Google this time didn't help me.
I'm making my apps using cordova. I read that phone gap comes from cordova. I read also that now they are almost the same (if you open phone gap website it talks about cordova and gives cordova examples, so...).

Now my question is: in an app created with cordova, can I use a plugin for phonegap?

Example: just made work pushplugin for cordova (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin). Now it says it's deprecated and to use phonegap-push-plugin (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) that is also completely different (and, if you're interested, already has problems with beta iOS 9).

So, if I have an app already made with cordova, can I add this new plugin?
Using `phonegap plugin add phonegap-plugin-push` or `cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use latest push plugin in cordova by using `cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push`, if you have cordova verison >= 5.0 . Cordova and Phonegap both use same plugins almost.You can resolve your confusion about phongap and cordova from this http://phonegap.com/2012/03/19/phonegap-cordova-and-what%E2%80%99s-in-a-name/ ,but in short any plugin which is used in phonegap, can be used for cordova and vice versa. You can find different ids for same plugin like , for example for push plugin
`phonegap-plugin-push` and `cordova-plugin-push-notification`, but they both have same source code.
I am quoting a pargraph from post i mentioned :

> PhoneGap is a distribution of Apache Cordova. You can think of Apache
>   Cordova as the engine that powers PhoneGap, similar to how WebKit is
>   the engine that powers Chrome or Safari.

Comment: You are welcome. Please do upvote too, if it helped :)

Comment: Can't upvote: still newbie here and need more reputation. Just can mark correct answer. Sorry :-(

Comment: except for Chrome is not powered by WebKit